# Make dynamic/re-usable method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to use sendMessage in other method.
Like: 
    SendMessage('abc@expample.com','abc@exapmle.com','subject','body').

I am new to nodejs. Just need some syntax help.

I have tried 
    SendMessage.makeBody('','','','');
But its giving me error. 
TypeError: sendMessage.makeBody is not a function

```
function sendMessage(auth) {
  const raw = makeBody(
    'abc@example.com',
    'abc@example.com',
    'something',
    'something');
  gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    resource: {
     raw: raw
  }
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      logger.info('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    logger.info(response);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  sendMessage
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMessage(data) {
  gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth: data.auth,
    userId: 'me',
    resource: {
     raw: data.raw
  }
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      logger.info('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    logger.info(response);
  });
}

let raw = makeBody('abc@example.com','abc@example.com','something','something');
let data = {raw: raw, auth: auth}
// pass raw and auth both in a object and use it into sendMessage funtion.
sendMessage(data)

module.exports = {
  sendMessage
};
```